# Railroads on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

So I noticed that when the map is zoomed to 11-ish level, there are railway tracks. Is it possible to style the map to make railroads with more weight (bigger) and can be seen when zoomed out to level 6, for example? It won't be using the direction service, since I'm not doing any search from a place to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1) you can style the `transit.line` feature type. For example:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ff0280" },
      { "weight": 4 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that this does not only style *rail roads* but also *seaways*, and maybe more (unsure). And I don't think you can do anything about the zoom level at which it appears. But it's still a good way to make it stand out.

For the full list of feature types, you can refer to the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType).

There is a great tool to try these styles: the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this answer! +1 to you.

Comment: it helps a lot! but really can't tell the difference between seaways and rails.

Comment: Well, usually seaways are in water and railways are not ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to make the tick marks on the rails visible when zoomed out?

Comment: Not that I know, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this? [Rail.kmz](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=200707620502192605232.0004d99f99aebed2adc23&dg=feature)

Comment: Well, I don't have any GIS info about the rails. But thank you!